# Highlight all words containing a letter in a richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

How do i highlight all words containing a letter in a richtextbox. If i want to highlight the words that contain the letter "a" ,like the words hat or candle then highlight both words. 
I'm using c# using winform.

```
 private void button208_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HighlightPhrase(richTextBox1, "a", Color.Yellow);  
}
```

This highlights all words with a letter "a" but i'm not sure how to length to spaces then highlight.
Thanks.

Comment: is that a WinForms rich text box or a WPF (or something else) control?

Comment: Winforms and WPF controls are different. Please complete your question.

Comment: Yes a Winform richtextbox.

Comment: use this link http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=146

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab8wkhy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to find the occurrences of the substring you're looking for. Then, use the [SelectionBackColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionbackcolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to change the back color to the highlight color for each occurrence.

```
int len = richTextBox.TextLength;
int index = 0;
string textToFind = "a";

// this will highlight the text you're looking for
while ( index < len )
{
   richTextBox.Find(textToFind, index, len, RichTextBoxFinds.None);
   richTextBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
   index = richTextBox.Text.IndexOf(textToFind, index) + textToFind.Length;
}
```

If you want to highlight the whole words that contain a certain letter, then whenever you find an occurrence of the letter, you'll need to search for word boundaries (left and right of the index of the letter) and once you've identified them select the whole word using the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4fh98s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method of the RichTextBox control.

```
richTextBox.Select(wordBoundaryStart, wordBoundaryEnd - wordBoundaryStart);
```

Comment: lastIndex is giving me a does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @DARCOM8 - that was supposed to be `len`, sorry. Were you able to figure it out?